# How to create layout similler to Android Dialer App or Google Play Music

Tags: android, gridview, grid

I'm new to Android development. I want to create **tiles with its option menu (Three Dots)**  similar to Android dialler app or Google Play Music in my layout shown in following image.
[image: Android 4.4.4 Dialler (built-in)]

[image: Google Play Music]


I want to know how to implement this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layout that you will use for all the item to show. This layout should then have an ImageButton with the image source set to an drawable icon. (See https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Then create a grid view to show all items.

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html for information about creating layouts.

Comment: According to you, I've to create layout for Grid item similar to listitem in list view and I want to know that which is better control for displaying THREE dots for option. it's imageView, Simple Button or other control.

Comment: I think you should use an ImageButton, but I guess you could use whatever view you would like.
I forgot to also recommend that you look at the section "Creating a Popup Menu" in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu